# Function pointer memory usage

Tags: c++, memory, function-pointers

How much memory would it take to declare a function pointer. How about a function pointer pointing to a member function of a class?

[EDIT:] I guess my question wasn't clear. I am aware a function pointer to a member function takes up more memory space, I am wondering why...

Comment: This is platform-dependent. Use `sizeof`.

Comment: Technically, *declaring* one does not take any memory at run time. *Defining* one does. And yes, you have to use `sizeof` to find out the size.

Comment: Afaik, a pointer takes up a word; regardless of what it points to. The word size is system dependant though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That's not necessarily true on many platforms. For example, on computers with Harvard architecture (separate memory spaces for programs and data) the pointer sizes are often different, depending on memory type.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh, thanks. Never even heard of "Harvard Architecture".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to the implementation, but typically a pointer to a member function takes up the same amount of space a regular pointer takes up, plus the amount of space the offset to the `this` pointer takes, which is typically the same size as a pointer. So you would expect a pointer to a member function to be twice the size of a regular pointer.

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
    int q;
    Base() { ; }
    void BaseFunc () { cout << this << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    int r;
    Derived() { ; }
    virtual void DerivedFunc () { cout << this << endl; }
};

int main ()
{
    Derived f;
    f.BaseFunc();
    f.DerivedFunc();
    void (*p1)();
    void (Derived::*p2)();

    cout << sizeof(p1) << " "  << sizeof(p2) << endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
0x7fffe4c3e328
0x7fffe4c3e320
8 16
```

So a pointer to a member function has to store two pieces of information -- which function to call and how to adjust the `this` pointer to point to the right section of the member data.

And for those who think the adjuster can be computed from the types, try this `main`:

```
int main ()
{
    Derived f;

    void (Derived::*p1)();
    p1 = &Derived::BaseFunc;
    (f.*p1)();
    p1 = &Derived::DerivedFunc;
    (f.*p1)();
}
```

The two invocations of `(f.*p1)();` require different adjusters even though the types are the same. And, of course, invoking `BaseFunc` through a `Base::(*)()` pointer would require a different adjuster from invoking the same function through a `Derived::(*)()` pointer.

Comment: the address isn't part of the type

Comment: By "offset" in my previous comments I meant an indicator of which member function to call. I read over [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx) which describes the same implementation you have in mind. I don't yet see how it is necessary to store the "adjustor" as it can be computed from the two types involved. I will post a new question about it instead of having chat in comments though.  Removing my previous comments accordingly

Comment: @MattMcNabb It can't be computed from the two types involved. The two types can be the same and the adjuster can be different. See [here](http://pastebin.com/B41JLX9Y) for an example. The two invocations of `(f.*p1)();` involve the same types but require different adjusters. (Updated answer too.)

Comment: In your linked example, if I add `cout << sizeof p1 << endl;` then the output is `18ff4c 1844fc 4`. A better example might be if you include 2 base classes, although that would still only demonstrate that `this` changes, not that an adjustor is required. The adjustment can be computed when the call is made because the compiler knows that if a pointer to `&Derived::Base2Func` is being called then adjustment is required

Answer (score 4):

The answer is platform-dependent. You could find the answer for your specific platform by using `sizeof`.

Size of pointer to member function may not necessarily be the same as that of a regular function pointer, so you should write a test to output them both:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo() {}
struct C {
    void bar();
};
int main() {
    cout << sizeof(&foo) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(&C::bar) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SUCYfs)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am curious how the size of the function pointer to member function is determined?

Comment: @CodeNoob The compiler writer decides that. They figure out how much memory they need to store the data required to call a function through a pointer, and return that as the size of a function pointer.